# Neo4j merge properties from a text file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to merge properties from a text file with existing nodes in neo4j? My text file is in the form of id, property. The ids match the nodes I already have in neo4j. I am trying to match all the node types which all have an id to the ids of the text file and add the new property. I now tried this but it is taking forever to finish. Moreover can I do it on all nodes not on just Songs nodes - I just leave it as MATCH (c)?

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///page_rank.txt' AS  line 
MATCH (c:Songs)
WHERE c.id=toInt(line[0]) 
SET c.pageRank = toFloat(line[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Let's say I have four existing nodes in my database:

```
(a:Person {id: 01})

(b:Person {id: 02})

(c:Person {id: 03})

(d:Dog {id: 04})
```

And let's say I want to merge some properties on them - I don't want to create new nodes - just add these properties to the existing nodes.

So I have a CSV file called 'nodes_prop.csv' that looks like the following:

```
id,property
01,blue
02,green
03,grey
04,black
```

If I want to use merge (it sounds to me like you could possibly get away with just using MATCH - SET for your use case) to match on the id's of the nodes and set the property (based on values in CSV file), regardless of the label of the node, I could use the following cypher query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes_prop.csv" AS line
MERGE (a {id: toInteger(line.id)})
ON MATCH SET a.eye_color=line.property
RETURN *;
```

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason for it "taking forever to finish" is that you do not have [an index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:Song(id)`, and so the `MATCH/WHERE` clauses have to scan through the `Song` node to find each `id`.

You can create the index you need this way:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Song(id)
```

However, if you want to make essentially the same query, but for all nodes (not just `Song` nodes), you will not be able to use "normal" indexes, as above. Instead, for good performance, you'd need to use [explicit indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/indexing/), which requires much more effort on your part to use.